# 3 partitions, cloning to larger disk; preserve GRUB?

Tags: grub, clone

I've got a 10 GB ext3 partition, a ~512 MB linux-swap partition, and a 45.4 GB NTFS partition. I have GRUB doing my bootloading.

I'm looking to clone it all to a new 160 GB hard drive I got today and then expand my NTFS partition to the top (presumably with GParted). I have Clonezilla - will this work well for getting everything across, including GRUB?

Also to note - I have a 160 GB drive in an enclosure that I can remove it from - it's my backup drive of sorts and I have around 60 GB free on it.

Comment: Great. Thanks Molly. Can I get a recommendation (anybody) as to whether I should image the drive and then copy from the image to the new drive or just put the new drive in my enclosure, boot Clonzilla Live and copy across?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have Clonezilla - will this work
>   well for getting everything across,
>   including GRUB?

in a word, yes.

edit: you can create a drive image and then restore the image to the new drive or clone the drive directly. the effect is the same, no difference, none whatsoever. :)

Comment: Thanks. I just added a comment to the question about whether I should image or copy directly. If you got info on that, that would also make me happy. =)

Comment: I cloned and restored to my new WD Scorpio Blue 160 last night. Sweet barbecue sauce, that thing is fast (compared to my old drive). Everything went pretty smooth. Thanks.

Comment: well done ... :)